# Google Charts, with MySQL, HTTPD getting crushed

Tags: javascript, apache, google-visualization

I'm developing a straight forward system to plot data we have stored in a mysql database. I'm using Google Charts API to make 3 scatter plot graphs with about 300 points each. These points are retrieved from the database with php.

The php page takes about 20 seconds to load ~50 points into each scatter plot, but when I try to do 300+, it takes forever...

I can watch the CPU usage on the local web server sky rocket to 90%, and it's 1 HTTPD process using up the CPU.

The data points are being searched for in a mysql table that is 82,000 rows and 19MB.

I'm actually not sure how to identify what is sucking up all these resources?

Would a faster webserver help?

Currently, it's running on a kind of lousy computer for testing:
C2D: E4600 @ 2.4ghz
3gb ram
5400rpm 500gb hd
running XAMPP on Windows XP Pro 64

I can transfer this all over to a bleeding edge quad-quad rig of ours, but I want to try to optimize as much as possible before I do.

Where should I start looking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should start looking at your php code. If all its doing is reading stuff from the database and writing to stdout, the httpd process (I'm assuming this is mod_php we're talking about) should barely register a performance blip. It sounds like your code is doing something you're not telling us about.

Try xdebug.